# How to broadcast a subset of a text string from a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to extract the year and rainfall values from messy text strings stored in a dataframe column and save these to new columns. I did it via list comprehensions, after testing with different slicing methods unsuccessfully. Is list comprehension the best way to extract a subset of a string for broadcasting?

Much thanks to all!

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['   1883   1    6.3     1.7       6   122.1     ---',
               '   1883   2    8.0     2.8       2    69.8     ---',
               '   1883   3    4.8    -1.6      23    29.6     ---',])
df['split'] = df[0].str.split()
df['year'] = [df['split'][i][0] for i in df.index]
df['rainfall'] = [float(df['split'][i][5]) for i in df.index]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['split'] = df[0].str.split()
df['year']=df['split'].map(lambda x:x[0])
df['rainfall']=df['split'].map(lambda x:x[5])
df=df[['year','rainfall']]
df
       year rainfall
    0  1883    122.1
    1  1883     69.8
    2  1883     29.6
```

Comment: Thank you for the code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its [long-term value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by describing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: I think the solution with the output is fairly clear to anyone having modicum knowledge of Python. Not adding any prespecified text beforehand doesn't make it any less clear.